# COPY INTO path with wildcards = Index out of range

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm trying to use COPY INTO to ingest files within a folder on a Storage account (ADLS Gen2).

If I concatenate path of each files, it's working.

```
COPY INTO dbo.internal_heap
FROM 'https://storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/folderA/folderB/1.orc',
     'https://storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/folderA/folderB/2.orc',
     'https://storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/folderA/folderB/3.orc',
     'https://storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/folderA/folderB/4.orc'
WITH (
    FILE_TYPE = 'ORC'
    ,CREDENTIAL=(IDENTITY= 'Managed Identity')
)
```

If I'm using wilcards like this :

```
COPY INTO dbo.internal_heap
    FROM 'https://storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/folderA/folderB/*.orc'
    WITH (
        FILE_TYPE= 'ORC'
        ,CREDENTIAL=(IDENTITY= 'Managed Identity')
    )
```

I have this error :

```
Msg 110813, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: startIndex
```

Any clue ?

Answer (score 2):

I got an asnwer from the Synapse team.

If all ORC file names are starting from 'part-' you need to specify your location like this :

```
COPY INTO dbo.internal_heap
    FROM 'https://storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/folderA/folderB/part-*.orc'
    WITH (
        FILE_TYPE= 'ORC'
        ,CREDENTIAL=(IDENTITY= 'Managed Identity')
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/copy-into-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest#arguments) shows that wildcards are possible but does make the following recommendation:

> For best performance, avoid specifying wildcards that would expand
>   over a larger number of files. If possible, list multiple file
>   locations instead of specifying wildcards.

The docs also state that "wildcard expansion is applied *recursively*..." so I would **guess** your error is occurring because you have multiple folders?  Try removing any other folders you have in the same parent directory just as a debugging exercise.

`COPY INTO` is still in preview so there may be a little buggette or two at this point in time.  Consider raising a support request with MS via the Azure portal.

Comment: I don't have nested folders so yes this is strange

Comment: What's the performance like for COPY INTO btw?  Feel free to update the other question, upvote or mark as answer if it's been helpful to you!   : )

Comment: Sure i will update the other ;) right now, in regard of performance, i need to go further with COPY INTO

Comment: Paging @RonDunn.

Comment: Quick update on performance. This is more or less identical in regard of Polybase. Same files, same volume, same resutls. Here 6GB of ORC files in 24 minutes (DW1000c/staticrc80)

Comment: You might experiment with what table type you are loading in to, ie CTAS is the recommendation with Polybase but with COPY INTO the table must exist.  So try clustered index, columnstore with round robin, columnstore hash distributed etc